# triangle-inequality for similarity functions

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove triangle-inequality for any similarity function.

The axioms for a distance are:

${\rm dist}(x,y) \geq 0$

${\rm dist}(x,y)= {\rm dist}(y,x)$

if ${\rm dist}(x,y) = 0 $   then $ x = y $

triangle-inequality: $ {\rm dist}(x,z) \leq {\rm dist}(x,y) + {\rm dist}(y,z)$

If the similarity is inversely related to the distance, then the similarity must also satisfy the distance axioms.

But the Triangle Inequality does not hold for all similarity measures.

Does anyone know any similarity function of numerical data which satisfies the triangle-inequality?

Comment: Please see [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: There is no standard definition of similarity measure, so it might be helpful if you included yours in the question. In particular because if you require it to be the reciprocal of a distance, it is hardly going to fulfill the triangle inequality.